# Make sleep command with auto restart

Tags: windows-10

I see from this site how to make my computer go to sleep with dos command.

but my computer with a raid controller takes a long time to boot.

**Hence the question is:**

What is the dos command to put computer to sleep (*or hibernate or whatever*) with a time (*say one hour say 8 hours*) preset when it will come back on out of sleep ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot execute a command while the computer is at sleep or hybernation, so once your script puts the computer to sleep, it cannot get out of it from your script.

There is however the option in your BIOS to wake up a computer based on various settings, one is a preset time (eg. 8:00 am). Another option is to wake up your computer using a scheduled task.

**Putting the pc to sleep**
Putting the pc to sleep is simple.
Just a simple command to do that.

```
rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0
```

**Creating a scheduled task to wake up your computer from sleep**
To wake up the computer from sleep at a specific time is a bit more work.

Create a new task, and make the command be `cmd.exe` with parameter `/c "exit"`

On the `conditions` tab, check `Wake computer to run this task` and on the `trigger` tab, set it to daily with a specific time.

If you are really good in scripting, I suppose you could use schtasks to modify/create this task from your script and set the time, which would allow you to set that 8 hour delay you wish for depending on when you run the task.

Lastly, if you edit/create the scheduled task from your script, do so before putting the computer to sleep ;) otherwise it'll modify/create the task after the computer comes out of sleep again. :)

Comment: i completely understand your analysis. thank you. But I did not yet win the ring. I checked bios and no time setting. I carefully prepared a start up the computer and do a task in taskscheduler and it did not start up. i tried twice. I waited 5 minutes after the start time before using the mouse to start the computer. As I cannot see any flaws in this idea I am going to test it on another computer. Thanks again. Roe5685.

Comment: If you are unable to wake up your computer from sleep, go into your BIOS and change the method of sleeping. I believe you have S1 and S3 where S3 will completely put the pc to sleep and S1 only some of the functions. S1 is more likely to work than S3.